# Ignore error "Module 'arcpy.da' has no 'SearchCursor' member" in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arcpy

I develop many scripts with arcpy in VS Code, and every time I use a Cursor, VSCode thinks it is an error:

[image]

It does not affect the scripts performance, but, is there any way to make VS Code ignore this particular kind of (what it interpret as) errors?

Just so that they are not displayed in the problems panel.

Comment: Most likely these methods are generated by code and can't be analyzed statically by PyLint, You can write a PyLint extension or add a brain to astroid like I did for turtle https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/issues/849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the recurrence of the problem, please allow me to take the module "cv2" as an example.

We can add the following settings in "`settings.json`" to ignore the warnings of the module "cv2" and not ignore the problems from other modules. (Since pylint information provides suggestions for us to edit code, it is recommended that you make sure that the code can be executed before closing its information.)

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generated-members=cv2.*"],
```

before:

[image]

after:

[image]